# Upgraded project to NestJS 10. Middleware stopped working

Tags: nestjs, middleware

My project was originally version 7 of NestJS.  The code was set to run in Node 12.  Since 12 is being EOLed, I upgraded to Node 20 and NestJS 10.

Everything seems to be running ok, but the Middleware stopped working for some reason.  I tried to make a sample app on stackblitz.  For some reason on there, part of my middleware works, but the functional middleware doesn't seem to still.

In my real app, neither sets of middleware work.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nestjs-typescript-starter-vgmxni?file=src%2Fcommon%2Fmiddleware%2Frequest-id.middleware.ts

The code for my modules is like this in both:

```
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
    consumer.apply(createRequestId(), HttpRequestInfoMiddleware).forRoutes(AppController);
```